# Upper case using mhchem and glossaries

Tags: glossaries, capitalization, mhchem

I'm having the following trouble using `mhchem` in my glossaries. I'd like to not have to worry about whether I've used an acronym already when I start out a sentence, but I'm finding that `\Gls` does not seem to work very well with `mhchem` in `glossaries`. I can work around by trying to keep track of whether or not I've used the acronym yet, but I'd love to be able to make an edit in my `\newacronym` definitions to make it work. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % Load the package
\makeglossaries % Prepare the glossary
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newacronym{CO2}{\ce{CO2}}{carbon dioxide}
\newacronym{CH4}{CH$_4$}{methane}
\newacronym{H2SO4}{\NoCaseChange{\ce{H2SO4}}}{sulfuric acid}

\begin{document}
    %I'd like the following to work, but it doesn't...
    \Gls{CO2} in the environment \ldots 
    \Gls{CO2} now generates an error

    \Gls{CH4} in the environment \ldots
    \Gls{CH4} works fine.

    %\gls works fine
    Calculation of the corresponding \gls{CO2} emissions to cover the surplus in electricity demand.

    %I also tried
    \Gls{H2SO4} is an acid. We use \gls{H2SO4} everyday. 
    \Gls{H2SO4} generates an error \ldots
    \gls{H2SO4} is okay.

    \printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
    %\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newacronym{CO2}{{}\ce{CO2}}{carbon dioxide}` should work

Comment: Just to expand on @clemens' comment: in the first case, `\Gls` is trying to do `\MakeTextUppercase\ce{CO2}` (so `\MakeTextUppercase` is trying to grab just `\ce` as the argument, which causes an error). In the third case, `\Gls` is trying to do `\MakeTextUppercase\NoCaseChange{\ce{H2SO4}}` (so `\MakeTextUppercase` is trying to grab `\NoCaseChange` as the argument, which causes an error). Internally `\Gls` is using `\makefirstuc`, which is described in more detail in the [mfirstuc manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/mfirstuc-manual.html).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot why does `\newacronym{CO2}{\empty\ce{CO2}}{carbon dioxide}` go wrong (similarly with `\relax`)? Since `\MakeTextUppercase\empty` compiles just fine I suspect the cause to be somewhere else…

Comment: @clemens It seems to be a problem with `\makefirstuc` since `\makefirstuc{\empty\ce{CO2}}` fails. It's probably something to do with the mechanism that's trying to determine if `\empty` has an argument. `\makefirstuc{\empty{}\ce{CO2}}` works fine, and there's also no problem if I replace `\ce` with another command, such as `\makefirstuc{\empty\textbf{CO2}}`. I'll look into it, but I think the simplest thing to do in this case is just `\newacronym{CO2}{{}\cs{CO2}}{carbon dioxide}`.

Comment: @clemens I've found the problem. It'll be fixed in the next release. D'you want to convert your comment into an answer? It's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Giving the underlying uppercasing macro (`\makefirstuc`) an empty group as first “token” for its work will do:

```
\newacronym{CO2}{{}\ce{CO2}}{carbon dioxide}
```

Without it `\ce` is the argument to `\makefirstuc` and things go wrong.